# Not to allow time picker to pick past time values

Tags: android, datetime, android-timepicker

I'm implementing a time picker dialog in my project. It should not pick past values with respect to current time. I mean to set minimum and maximum time for picking.

Below is the process for timepicker I have done:

```
 // Current Hour
 hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

 // Current Minute
 minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

 return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, false);
```

I have done the below process to date picker dialog. It worked, but for time picker I can't find any process.

For date picker :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, onDateSet, cYear, cMonth, cDay);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

So please help how to achieve this in time picker dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this as a starting point.

You extend TimePickerDialog and added 2 methods setMin and setMax.

In the onTimeChanged method check that the new time is valid with respect to the min/max times.

It still needs some polishing though...

```
public class BoundTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    private int minHour = -1, minMinute = -1, maxHour = 100, maxMinute = 100;

    private int currentHour, currentMinute;

    public BoundTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
    }

    public void setMin(int hour, int minute) {
        minHour = hour;
        minMinute = minute;
    }

    public void setMax(int hour, int minute) {
        maxHour = hour;
        maxMinute = minute;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        super.onTimeChanged(view, hourOfDay, minute);

        boolean validTime;
        if(hourOfDay < minHour) {
            validTime = false;
        }
        else if(hourOfDay == minHour) {
            validTime = minute >= minMinute;
        }
        else if(hourOfDay == maxHour) {
            validTime = minute <= maxMinute;
        }
        else {
            validTime = true;
        }

        if(validTime) {
            currentHour = hourOfDay;
            currentMinute = minute;
        }
        else {
            updateTime(currentHour, currentMinute);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not working on lollipop, only working on pre lollipop device.

Comment: Please give a better solution